# How to add padding (left & right) to each lines in CSS2 with only one SPAN? Tricky?

Tags: html, css

I can't find any solution to this problem.

Here's the render I want:
http://jsfiddle.net/kQSxb/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>
      <span>consectetur adipisicing elit, sed</span>
      <span>do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  float: left;
}
#container {
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: left;
}
#container span {
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Is it possible to have this exact render (paddings left and right for each lines, margin between each lines) with only ONE `<span>` (or `<p>`, or `<div>`) in the `<div>#container`?

I want to add padding - to the left and to the right - each lines.
So, the words **consectetur** and **do** must have left padding, and the words **amet**, **sed** (and the dot) must have right padding.

If not, is it possible to do this with CSS3, or maybe with jQuery hack?

Thank you!

ps: sorry guys, I wasn't clear enough. I've edited my post. :-/

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? Also, please post your code in the question.

Comment: i didn't understand the question properly. do you want alternative padding right and left ??

Comment: I've edited my question with one more jsFiddle to show the render I want. Do you think it will be better if I paste the whole html+css in my post?

Comment: There are four answers that seem to answer this question, but you commented they are not the desired solution. You only point to your fiddle for reference, but it is not clear to me/us. Could you please be specific about your wishes? For starters: does every line need a bottom margin of 3 px?

Comment: Yes you have edited, but before that , you haven't add a  correct details, what do you want exactly. In this case we can understand it, but it's absolutely unfair to give a  minus to us ...

Comment: Ok guy, I'll refactor my question to be clearer. Sorry...

Comment: Done. There's one jsFiddle only to show what I'm looking for. The trick is to have the same render with one `span` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's my answer...

Obviously, it is impossible to do in CSS so we have to find another way to separate each lines.
A way to do this is to modify a little bit the markup and the stylesheet and parse the string to create a span for each line rendered.

Ugly code:

```
String.prototype.spanify = function(nb_char) {
  var regex = '.{1,'+nb_char+'}(\\s|$)|\\S+?(\\s|$)';
  return '<span>' + this.match(RegExp(regex, 'g')).join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
};

$.fn.titleize = function() {
  var title = $(this).html();
  var title_calculated = '<span id="title" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">' + title + '</span>';
  $('body').append(title_calculated);
  var width = $(this).html(title).width() - 20;
  var full_width = $('body').find('#title').width();
  $('#title').remove();
  var nb_lines = Math.floor(full_width / width);
  var nb_char_per_line = Math.floor(title.length / nb_lines);
  var new_title = title.spanify(nb_char_per_line);
  $(this).html(new_title);
}
$('.title').titleize();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add the padding to `#container` and you're done.

```
#container {
  width: 260px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/M3SKj/1/

Also I think, it's rather unreliable to expect certain line-brakes, just by setting a width on  a container-element. Just my 2cents.

Comment: if done like this that means the container will stretch more than it's width? of which would be 330px?

Comment: @CharmingPrince I accounted for this, and reduced the container width from 300px to 260px.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but no, this is not the solution. I've edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: @Fro_oo Why the down vote? Just because it's no perfect answer is no reason to down vote. You could have just stated that you updated your answer and wait for a reply.

Comment: As I've said, the solution proposed don't answer the question and could misleading other people with the same demand. Sorry for the down vote. As you've said, I thought a high rated answer must be perfect. I'll not made the same mistake in the future. :-/ (I really need to improve my english..)

Comment: @Fro_oo Then just remove the down-vote. In my opinion only an accepted answer should be nearly perfect. And if this is not your answer then just wait for response after updating your question.

Comment: I can't undo the downvote right now, I must wait a little bit. So, do you see any solution? ;-)

Comment: @Fro_oo I don't see a solution without changeing the markup. Maybe you could explain why you actually want this, because maybe there are completely different approaches.

Comment: @Yoshi Well, I've answered my question. To do this, you have to parse the title and create many spans on the fly with some Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Does adding the code to  #container span solve your problem?

```
display: block;
```

Here's your code with it in - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/M3SKj/2/

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunatly no, this is not what I'm looking for. Please check the other jsFiddle for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done in CSS, certainly not in CSS 2 and likely not in CSS 3.

The single rows within a single span are generated by the browsers text rendering engine after applying the box model - there is just no CSS selector to select the rows individually.

The only (** very ** ugly) way to achieve what you want would be to count characters, compute the line-length and insert html white spaces and `<br>` s at the computed line ends.

Comment: Yeah, same conclusion for me. That's why I was thinking about a Javascript snippet to compute the text rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Yoshi is right.However, you can do it with  Jquery too. 
But you need to know, it's absolutely not elegant solution.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').css('padding', '0px 20px 0px 20px');
 });
```

Ahh, and also need to remove the padding from the span. 
And if you use padding and margin, be careful , IE(6) has a  different [box handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunatly no, this is not what I'm looking for. Please check the other jsFiddle for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is your updated class for span

```
#container span {
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunatly no, this is not what I'm looking for. Please check the other jsFiddle for more information.